# Why value on textbox is not updated in Form1.cs

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on c# window forms and stuck since long ago to solve a situation.
The situation is :
I have a GUI Form1.cs[Design] which consists of a Button and textbox (txtmsg here).

I have created a class Testing.cs in the visual studio winform project which contains the code like this :

```
namespace smallTesting
{
    class Testing
    {
        public Testing()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection String Did not found");
            Form1 frm = new Form1(); //I do this in order to have access to 
            //renderMessage() so that i will be able to update my output to             
            //textbox(txtMsg) in this function definition by calling it.
            int i = 1;
            for(;;)
            {
                if (i == 50)
                {
                    break;
                }
                frm.renderMessage(i.ToString());               
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Form1.cs class is:

```
namespace smallTesting
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
          InitializeComponent();

        }
        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //It should work on button click.
        {
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            Testing tst = new Testing();//Instantiate the class

        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        public void renderMessage(string str)
        {
            this.txtMsg.Text = str;
            MessageBox.Show("str :" + txtMsg.Text); //It should update my Textbox by 1 to 50 . BUT IT DONT DO.Whereas i can see the counting in the message box popuped.
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting the function call to renderMessage(string str) from class Testing must have updated the txtMsg but it don't do so. Why ? (whereas messagebox popuped shows that the string is updated for every call to this function) . Why the txtMsg is not updated in my GUI for each call? How to update it. 
Note: Please note that this txtMsg box updation mechanism must go from testing.cs to Form1.cs (Not Form1.cs to Testing.cs)

Comment: ok question.. in the `renderMessage` method you are calling `MessageBox.Show` that's find and dandy.. but how do you expect it to show when you have not called the `frm.Show()` method.. this looks pretty straight forward and easy to rectify have you also debugged the code..? also in this line `frm.renderMessage(i.ToString());` I would expect a `.ShowModal()` method call since you are doing this in a loop. I would really consider refactoring your code / logic as well

Comment: Why is this tagged with asp.net?

Comment: If I understand the flow of your code, you have a Form1 that is your main form and the startup of your code. Now in the constructor of this code you initialize a Testing class instance and in the constructor of that instance you initialize ANOTHER instance of form1. No wonder if you don't see anything. The message goes to the other instance not to the current one

Comment: @Tim I removed it. By mistake i done that.

Comment: @Steve Yes i got it. But how to make the value i.string() update to the txt.Msg of main form (Form1.cs) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Testing class to receive the instance of Form1 that you want to update the textbox

```
namespace smallTesting
{
    class Testing
    {
        public Testing(Form1 currentInstance)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection String Did not found");
            int i = 1;
            while(i < 50)
            {
                currentInstance.renderMessage(i.ToString());               
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the Form1 constructore change how do you initialize the Testing instance

```
namespace smallTesting
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
          InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //It should work on button click.
        {
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            // Pass the reference of the instance of Form1 that you
            // want to update. Do not let the Testing class creates its
            // own instance of form1, instead use THIS ONE.
            Testing tst = new Testing(this);
        }
        ......
    }
}
```